# Git push to Github shows vulnerability, but I've already updated the package and the info page is 404

Tags: git, security, github

I got the following warning when running `git push origin master` to push my repo to Github:

```
 GitHub found 1 vulnerability on username/someapp's default branch (1 high). To find out more, visit:
remote:      https://github.com/username/someapp/network/alerts
```

I already received an email indicating that lodash < 4.17.13 had a high severe vulnerability, and ran `npm update`, after which my lodash package has been updated to 4.17.15.

When I visited the `https://github.com/username/someapp/network/alerts` page, it was a 404 error.  So is the vulnerability resolved, even though I'm still getting this message when I push?

If this question is better suited for Security.Stackexchange then I'm happy to close here and repost there.

Comment: In my experience it takes the bot a while to get round to re-checking, so that is essentially a cached warning message. Give it a little time (say, 24 hours) and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you replace the "username" and "someapp" with your actual username and project name?

Comment: @max630, yes, I just swapped them in here in the question for privacy reasons.